# Excel table formulas throwing errors in google sheets

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, excel-tables

I have created some new formulas in my excel table by modifying one of the existing sheets.After converting to google sheets, the new formulas don't seem to have converted. The old formulas were converted just fine. What could be the potential reason for this?
Example of how the formulas are appearing in google sheets (At present it shows #ERROR) :

```
=_xlfn.IFNA(IF(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column4]]="Distance Activity",IF(AND(ISBLANK(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column5]]),Table1319[[#This Row],[Column10]]=_xlfn.IFNA(VLOOKUP(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column6]],_S3_Transport_EF[],11,FALSE),0)),Table1319[[#This Row],[Column9]], Table1319[[#This Row],[Column9]]/IF(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column10]]="mile", _xlfn.IFNA(VLOOKUP(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column5]]&" - "&Table1319[[#This Row],[Column6]], Mobile_S1_EF[#All], 11, FALSE),1), IF(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column10]]="km", _xlfn.IFNA(VLOOKUP(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column5]]&" - "&Table1319[[#This Row],[Column6]], Mobile_S1_EF[#All], 11, FALSE),1)*1.60934, IF(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column10]]="nautical mile", _xlfn.IFNA(VLOOKUP(Table1319[[#This Row],[Column5]]&" - "&Table1319[[#This Row],[Column6]], Mobile_S1_EF[#All], 11, FALSE),1)*0.868976)))), Table1319[[#This Row],[Column9]]), "")
```

Here is what I wrote in Excel :

```
=IFNA(IF([@Column4]="Distance Activity",IF(AND(ISBLANK([@Column5]),[@Column10]=IFNA(VLOOKUP([@Column6],_S3_Transport_EF,11,FALSE),0)),[@Column9], [@Column9]/IF([@Column10]="mile", IFNA(VLOOKUP([@Column5]&" - "&[@Column6], Mobile_S1_EF[#All], 11, FALSE),1), IF([@Column10]="km", IFNA(VLOOKUP([@Column5]&" - "&[@Column6], Mobile_S1_EF[#All], 11, FALSE),1)*1.60934, IF([@Column10]="nautical mile", IFNA(VLOOKUP([@Column5]&" - "&[@Column6], Mobile_S1_EF[#All], 11, FALSE),1)*0.868976)))), [@Column9]), "")
```

Comment: Why are you working with Excel instead of working directly with GSheets? some formulas cannot be translated from Excel to sheets and vice versa.

Comment: @MikeSteelson, I need both versions to work. There is no new formula I introduced here.

Comment: ok, can you share your spreadsheet as a minimal reproducible example and explain the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems on of table names were not compatible with google sheets. The table name starts with underscore `_S3_Transport_EF`. After I changed it to `S3_Transport_EF` all my formulas seemed to work